# What is the best layout to get an image from multiple sources?

Tags: mobile, layout, design

I have a mobile application and would like a better image getting layout. Image sources:

URL,
 Local file,
 Camera,
 Facebook

It's a simple mobile picture application and I would like to develop a better user interface.

Thank You,
Zoltan

[image: My app]

Comment: I'm confused... What're you trying to do? Create an image sharing site? Is it desktop, mobile tablet or all? Please give more details so we can better help you!

Comment: Instead of just adding screenshots, can you explain what it is exactly you're asking for here? It's very unclear. What does "a better image getting layout" mean?

Comment: A way how to obtain images from various sources. I think filip has a good idea to achieve that, and clicking any of popup menu item will open a new view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to provide some more context, but a simple popup menu sounds like a good idea.
[image: multiple image sources]